# Can a flask route return both an IO stream and a variable?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm using a flask route to generate a QR code as a byte stream, which is called fairly simply on the homepage with a jinja2 template like this:

```
#INDEX.HTML
<img src="{{ url_for('qr') }}">
```

This works but there is another variable within the route function (`cost`) that I would also like to render on the homepage but I'm not sure how to return it. I've tried returning a `render_template` including `cost=cost` and calling it with `{{cost}}` but it doesn't appear and the QR code doesn't render. Is it possible to return both an IO stream AND variables within a return statement or somehow pass a variable to the index route?

Here is the route function:

```
#ROUTES.PY
@app.route('/qr', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def qr():
    conversion = requests.get(API_ADDRESS)
    cost = conversion*10
    basestring = pyqrcode.create(cost, error='H')
    stream = BytesIO()
    basestring.svg(stream, scale=5)
    return stream.getvalue(), 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'}
```

Comment: Better show code with template which uses `{{ cost }}` because it is the only method to send value and stream.

Comment: what is the problem to use `@app.route('/qr/<value>'` and `{{ url_for('qr', value=cost) }}` ?

Comment: @furas Something like this is what I'm looking for but this didn't work for me. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It is minimal working example which creates page with `{{ cost }}` and with `QRcode` generated by `@app.route('/qr/<int:cost>')` and `{{ url_for('qr', cost=cost) }}`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import pyqrcode
from io import BytesIO
import random


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    #conversion = requests.get(API_ADDRESS)
    
    conversion = random.randint(1, 9)
    cost = conversion*10

    return render_template_string('''Cost: {{ cost }}<br>
<img src="{{ url_for('qr', cost=cost) }}">''', cost=cost)


@app.route('/qr/<int:cost>') #, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def qr(cost):
    base_string = pyqrcode.create(cost, error='H')
    stream = BytesIO()
    base_string.svg(stream, scale=5)

    return stream.getvalue(), 200, {
        'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Expires': '0'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. So does this confirm that it is indeed impossible for a route function to return both a stream and a variable - it must be done in two separate routes?

Comment: stream can send only stream. You could send image with other items as JSON but it would need JavaScript with AJAX to get it and put in expected places in HTML. Using `/qr/<int:cost>` to generate image seems natural method - especially that you rather need send `cost` to `/qr/` to generate correct image. BTW: all  portals/APIs work this way - ie. [https://placekitten.com/](https://placekitten.com/) sends you image based on values which you use in url - ie. [http://placekitten.com/g/200/300](http://placekitten.com/g/200/300)